# Ensemble Stacking method - ValueError: Filler values must be provided

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, ensemble-learning

I am running this model to ensemble a Neural Network and a Random Forest.

I got the the accuracy for the Random Forest model. However, after that I got a error that says.

ValueError: Filler values must be provided when X has more than 2 training features.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGRbM.png)

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

from sklearn import datasets

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from mlxtend.classifier import StackingClassifier

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split

from mlxtend.plotting import plot_learning_curves
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

pick = open('data.pickle','rb')
data = pickle.load(pick)
pick.close()

epochs = 23
batch_size = 15

features = []
labels = []

for feature , label in data:
    features.append(feature)
    labels.append(label)

X=np.array(features)
y= np.array(labels)

#Activation Function
def swish (x):
    return K.sigmoid(x)*x

def build_ann():
    CNN= Sequential()

    CNN.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape =(224,224,1)))
    CNN.add(Activation(swish))
    
    
    CNN.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3)))
    CNN.add(Activation(swish))
    
    
    CNN.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    
    CNN.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3)))
    CNN.add(Activation(swish))
    
    
    CNN.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3)))
    CNN.add(Activation(swish))
    
    CNN.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    
    #Turns inputs into a vector
    CNN.add(Flatten())
    
    # Fully connected layer
    CNN.add(Dense(512))
    CNN.add(Activation(swish))
    
    CNN.add(Dense(2))
    CNN.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    
    CNN.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return CNN

clf1=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, 
                               criterion='gini')
clf2= KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_ann, nb_epoch=epochs, 
                        batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
lr = LogisticRegression()

sclf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1, clf2], 
                          meta_classifier=lr)

label = ['Random Forest', 'KerasNet', 'Stacking Classifier']
clf_list = [clf1, clf2, sclf]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
grid = itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2)



clf_cv_mean = []
clf_cv_std = []
for clf, label, grd in zip(clf_list, label, grid):
        
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
    print ("Accuracy: %.2f (+/- %.2f) [%s]" %(scores.mean(), 
                                              scores.std(), label))
    clf_cv_mean.append(scores.mean())
    clf_cv_std.append(scores.std())
        
    clf.fit(X, y)
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[grd[0], grd[1]])
    fig = plot_decision_regions(X=X, y=y, clf=clf)
    plt.title(label)

plt.show()

#plot classifier accuracy    
plt.figure()
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(range(4), clf_cv_mean, 
                            yerr=clf_cv_std, c='blue', fmt='-o', capsize=5)
for cap in caps:
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(1)                                                                                                                                
plt.xticks(range(3), ['RF', 'KN', 'Stacking'])        
plt.ylabel('Accuracy'); plt.xlabel('Classifier'); plt.title('Stacking Ensemble');
plt.show()


#plot learning curves
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
    
plt.figure()
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, sclf, print_model=False, style='ggplot')
plt.show()
```

can someone please help me. I have tried many unsuccessfully ways of ensembling using KerasClassifier.

Comment: Please provide the error traceback, and preferably include a dataset so that this is a MRE.  From what you have so far, it doesn't sound to be an issue with the stacking ensemble at all, but rather with your keras model.

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for answering. The data set is comprised for 5,000 images of two clases (2,500 each), it has a resolution of 224x224 and in greyscale. The deep network was done using tf.keras. in here I am trying to create a KerasClassfier from it. I included a picture of the error above, in the description